# How to make sidebar work with custom javascript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a sidebar menu that I'm trying to integrate with a Laravel PHP app. The sidebar appears fine on the display page when I run the app, but the animation, dropdown, and toggle do not work when the application is run.

The HTML has no problems:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="overlay"></div>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                Brand
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
        <span class="hamb-top"></span>
        <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
        <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

The CSS is also working with the sidebar

```
    body {
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
 }
body,
html { height: 100%;}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {background-color: transparent;}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*           Wrappers            */
/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
padding-left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left: 220px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
left: 220px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -220px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
background: #1a1a1a;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 220px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 70px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin-right: -220px;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*     Sidebar nav styles        */
/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 220px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
position: relative;
line-height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
height: 100%;
width: 3px;
background-color: #1c1c1c;
-webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
-moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
-ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
transition: width .2s ease-in;

}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
color: #fff;
background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
background-color: #79aefe;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
background-color: #314190;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
background-color: #279636;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
background-color: #7d5d81;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
background-color: #ead24c;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
background-color: #2d2366;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
background-color: #35acdf;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
-moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
-ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
transition: width .2s ease-in;

}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
color: #ddd;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus{
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
height: 65px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
background-color: #222;
box-shadow: none;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*       Hamburger-Cross         */
/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
margin-left: 15px;
background: transparent;
border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 100px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
height: 4px;
width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
top: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
top: 50%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
bottom: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
bottom: 0;
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
top: 50%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle { display: none; }
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 100px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
-webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*            Overlay            */
/*-------------------------------*/

.overlay {
position: fixed;
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
z-index: 1;
}
```

Javascript is the part of the program that is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    isClosed = false;

trigger.click(function () {
    hamburger_cross();
});

function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
    } else {
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
    }
}

$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
});
```

This is the code that I have for the master.blade.php file in my Laravel app

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('src/css/app.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('src/css/components/sidebar.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="row">
            @include('layouts.partials.sidebar')
        </header>
        <div id="main" class="row">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('src/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('src/script-components/sidebar.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I organize the javascript files in master.blade.php file to make the sidebar work?

Comment: Can you give us a live fiddle or website to inspect?

Comment: What is in the javascript console?

Comment: Here is a link to a jsfiddle environment: https://jsfiddle.net/techguy47/unqkhyLt/1/

Comment: The fiddle environment is for the sidebar that I have. I'm also wanting to customize the sidebar, but want to make sure this code works.